# Create a timetable with CoreData

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm new to Stack Overflow and have my first question.
I want to develop an application with a timetable. I've one UITableViewController and one CoreData entity called 'SchoolClass'. With arrow buttons I can switch between the days of a week. My problem is that I want to have all classes in the entity 'SchoolClass'. When I fetch the data I set the sectionNameKeyPath to 'day'.
But how can I use only one section that the UITableViewController only shows the classes of **one** day?
I hope you can help me!
And sorry for my bad english!! :)
qPaul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html)

> > A Fetch Request is a self-contained query which is sent to the Managed Object Context. The Context evaluates the request and returns the results in the form of an NSArray.
> >
> > The only thing a Fetch Request must have is an Entity. If you send a fetch request to the Context with only an Entity, you'll get an array of all known instances of that Entity.
> >
> > You can supply a Predicate if you want to only return instances that match certain criteria.

You should visit this tutorial by [Cocoadevcentral](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000086.php#13).